# Trying to understand some HTML5Boilerplate items

Tags: css, html, boilerplate

In the [**HTML5Boilerplate**](http://html5boilerplate.com/), on line 72 to 80 in the css, it says:

```
/* fonts.css from the YUI Library: developer.yahoo.com/yui/
   Refer to developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssfonts/ for font sizing percentages

   There are three custom edits:
   * remove arial, helvetica from explicit font stack
   * we normalize monospace styles ourselves
   * table font-size is reset in the HTML5 reset above so there is no need
   * to repeat
*/
body { font:13px/1.231 sans-serif; *font-size:small; } /* hack retained to
                                                          preserve specificity 
                                                       */
```

**What I'm trying to understand is, why do they mention Yahoo and what 'hack is retained?'**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The link to Yahoo is a link to the [Yahoo User Interface library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssfonts/), they have a thing there that

> ...provides cross-browser typographical normalization and control while still allowing users to choose and adjust their font size.

This means that Boilerplate uses the YUI Fonts.css as their base, but have removed Arial and Helvetica from the YUI Css file, have normalised monospace styles themselves and have I guess removed the table font-size because it's already in their HTML5 reset.

The hack is a CSS hack that targets IE6: `*font-size:small;` will only be seen by IE6 and below.

Hope some of that helps a bit.

Comment: +1 The fonts.css they are talking about is [this YUI css file](http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?3.3.0/build/cssfonts/fonts.css) so they name the original source and explain what they changed, and why.